# Scala and Mockito with traits

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mockito, scalatest

I had a simple class that naturally divided into two parts, so I refactored as

```
class Refactored extends PartOne with PartTwo
```

Then the unit tests started failing.

Below is an attempt to recreate the problem. The functionality of all three examples is the same, but the third test fails with a NullPointerException as indicated.  What it is about the use of traits that is causing the problem with mockito?

**Edit:** Is Mockito the best choice for Scala?  Am I using the wrong tools?

```
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitSuite
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import org.mockito.Mockito.when
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.Before

class A(val b:B)
class B(val c:Int)

class First(){
  def getSomething(a:A) = a.b.c
}

class Second_A extends Second_B
class Second_B{
  def getSomething(a:A) = a.b.c
}

class Third_A extends Third_B
trait Third_B{
  // Will get a NullPointerException here 
  // since a.b will be null
  def getSomething(a:A) = a.b.c
}

class Mocking extends JUnitSuite with MockitoSugar{
    var mockA:A = _
    @Before def setup { mockA = mock[A] }

    @Test def first_PASSES {
      val mockFirst = mock[First]
      when(mockFirst.getSomething(mockA)).thenReturn(3)

      assert(3 === mockFirst.getSomething(mockA))
    }

    @Test def second_PASSES {
      val mockSecond = mock[Second_A]
      when(mockSecond.getSomething(mockA)).thenReturn(3)

      assert(3 === mockSecond.getSomething(mockA))
    }

    @Test def third_FAILS {
      val mockThird = mock[Third_A]

      //NullPointerException inside here (see above in Third_B)
      when(mockThird.getSomething(mockA)).thenReturn(3) 

      assert(3 === mockThird.getSomething(mockA))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems Mockito has some kind of problem seeing the relationship between class and trait. Guess this is not that strange since traits are not native in Java. It works if you mock the trait itself directly, but this is maybe not what you want to do? With several different traits you would need one mock for each:

```
@Test def third_PASSES {
  val mockThird = mock[Third_B]

  when(mockThird.getSomething(mockA)).thenReturn(3)

  assert(3 === mockThird.getSomething(mockA))
}
```

Comment: I considered mocking it directly, but it seemed less clean than testing the overall class.  Well, it's a good enough work around for now.