# Scala, PlayFramework, Mockito, ExecutionContext null

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, scalatest

Following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30806548/4496364
I use Play's ExecutionContext in my project.

Recently I needed to use Mockito to test some services in Play.
So, this is simplified version of it:

```
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, ExecutionContext }
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

case class Model(id: Int, name: String)

trait DAO {
  def findAll(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[Model]]
}

class Service(dao: DAO) {
  def findAll: Future[List[Model]] = dao.findAll
}
```

Test:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
// doesn't work when different ExecutionContext
// import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global


class FuturesTest extends PlaySpec with MockitoSugar with ScalaFutures {

  "Service" should {
    "return all future data" in {
      val mockModel = Model(1, "name")
      val mockDAO = mock[DAO]
      when(mockDAO.findAll) thenReturn Future.successful(List(mockModel))

      val service = new Service(mockDAO)
      val futureData = service.findAll
      whenReady(futureData) { data =>
        data.map(_.name) must contain(mockModel.name)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Note the comment in test, i get a `NullPointException` when calling `dao.findAll` in the `Service`. At first I thought that Mockito can't handle Scala's Futures but I figured out that the `ExecutionContext` is the problem. Since I'm not a concurrency expert, can someone please explain why does this happen?

Comment: Maybe it could an issue not with ExecutionContext, but with `trait`?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243467/scala-and-mockito-with-traits?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone is looking, the answer was obvious...

```
import org.mockito.Matchers.any
..
mockDAO.findAll(any[ExecutionContext])
```

I wasn't familiar with how Mockito works, or with Scala implicits.
When you don't pass `any[ExecutionContext]` Scala will fill it with the implicit one from the test.